How to make a Qt function not log to console?
I have this in my code:
QString input = in.readLine();
if (!s.computers_font.fromString(input)){
    s.computers_font = backup.computers_font;
}

I want that if the input string is corrupt or empty, it should take the backup font (I assume the bool returned indicates whether the function call was successful). I think that part is working alright. However, it also logs the following message to the console:
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'

How can I suppress the logging behavior?

How about if( input.isEmpty() || ...?

That wouldn't handle the case where it's corrupt

The code you HAVE handles that case.

The code I have makes sure we still have a font setting, even if the input is corrupt. We're trying to make sure it doesn't log a message when the input is corrupt

Qt uses qDebug(), qWarning(), qCritical(), and qFatal() for logging. You can install a custom message handler to intercept these messages and prevent them from being printed to the console.
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

// Custom message handler
void myMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg) {
    // You can log the messages to a file or simply ignore them
    // Uncomment the following line to ignore the messages
    // return;

    // Example of logging to a file
    QFile outFile("log.txt");
    outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);
    QTextStream ts(&outFile);
    ts << msg << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Install the custom message handler
    qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageHandler);

    // Your application code here

    return app.exec();
}


You should add some type of synchronisation since myMessageHandler might be called from different threads.
